# how to search for letters which are next to each other?

Tags: python, string

string = 'woraaadaaaa';

If I want to find if there is 'word' in string:

```
for x in string:
    if 'word' in string:
    print(word)
```

But I want to print it just when letters are next to each other, so for instance in string 'aaawordaaa' there is 'word', but in 'aaworad' not. How to do this?
This is what I am looking help in

Comment: is it the python code you are trying ?

Comment: Yes, python 3.6

Comment: You can use the `find` method of strings without any loop: `if string.find("word") != -1: print("Found 'word'")`. For more information look [here](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.find).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its just like the example below.

```
  s="aaawordaaa"
  if 'word' in s:
     print('word')
  else:
      print("did not find the word")
```

The mistake you were doing is looping through it and which is not required, because you were however looking for continuous appearance of the word "word"

In the above example since 'word' is present as a continuous appearance you will get your desired output.

Also have a look at [basic_tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_for_loop.htm) which shall help you understand much more.